# How to combine multiple filter value in single watch variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried to do multiple filter with update pagination using angular watch concept. But end up with creating multiple watch function for every filter value. I Knew its wrong way to do. I need help to overcome this issue.

In html i had three inputs value to do filter .One is by date , title and any(search.$) .

```
**Html code** :

<div ng-controller="ShowAnnouncementListing">
    <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="ex1">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="search.title" id="ex1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="ex2">Published Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="search.date" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="date"  id="ex2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="ex3">Keywords</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="search.$"  id="ex3" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

     <table class="table announcementList-table">
             <thead>
                 <tr class="announcement-header">
                     <th style="width: 76px;"> Type </th>
                     <th> Published Date </th>
                     <th> Announcements </th>
                 </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>                
                        <tr class="announcementList-National-section" ng-repeat="announcement in filtered = announcementListData | filter:search.date | filter:search.$ | filter:search.title | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">                     
                             <td class="announcementList-table-National-segment">
                                 <span class="National-label">{{announcement.type}}                  
                                 </span>
                                 <span class="announcementList-National-segment-triangle"></span>                 
                             </td>
                             <td class="announcementList-published-date-TD">
                                 <span class="national-date-segment">
                                     <span class="national-day-label"> {{announcement.date}} </span> 
                                     <p> {{announcement.month}}</p>
                                 </span>
                             </td>  
                             <td class="announcementList-announcement-title-TD">
                                 <span class="national-segment-content"> <span class="national-segment-text"> {{announcement.title}} </span>{{announcement.desc}}</span>
                             </td> 
                         </tr>
                 <tbody>
     </table>

     <pagination page="currentPage" max-size="noOfPages" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="entryLimit"></pagination>


</div>

**JS code** :

 var announcementJsonData = [  
                                 {                                       
                                     "title":"Annoncement1",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"05",
                                     "month":"July",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 }, 
                                 {                                           
                                     "title":"Annoncement2",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"15",
                                     "month":"August",
                                     "type":"Regionl",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {                                              
                                     "title":"Annoncement3",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"28",
                                     "month":"June",
                                     "type":"Regionl",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement4",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"21",
                                     "month":"July",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement5",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"10",
                                     "month":"July",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement6",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"14",
                                     "month":"July",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement7",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"07",
                                     "month":"July",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement8",
                                     "desc":"Aorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"23",
                                     "month":"July",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement9",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"17",
                                     "month":"July",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement10",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"16",
                                     "month":"August",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                     "title":"Annoncement11",
                                     "desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam adipiscing massa lacus.",
                                     "date":"05",
                                     "month":"September",
                                     "type":"National",
                                     "img":"image.jpg"
                                 }

                             ];

 var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);

         sampleApp.filter('startFrom', function () {
            return function (input, start) {
                if (input) {
                    start = +start;
                    return input.slice(start);
                }
                return [];
            };
        });

sampleApp.controller('ShowAnnouncementListing',['$scope','filterFilter',function($scope , filterFilter) {

            $scope.message = "This is Announcement Listing page";
            $scope.announcementListData = announcementJsonData;

            /* $scope.announcementListData = announcementJsonData;                                      
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.announcementListData.length;
             $scope.viewby = 5;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby ;
            $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show */

            /* $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
                 $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
            }; */

           /* $scope.pageChanged = function() {
                 console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
           }; */

           /* $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
                 $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
                 $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first paghe
            } */


            // create empty search model (object) to trigger $watch on update
            $scope.search = {};

            $scope.resetFilters = function () {
                // needs to be a function or it won't trigger a $watch
                $scope.search = {};
            };

            // pagination controls
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.announcementListData.length;
            $scope.entryLimit = 5; // items per page
            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);

            // $watch search to update pagination
            $scope.$watch('search.date', function (newVal, oldVal) {            
                $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.announcementListData, newVal);
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
                $scope.currentPage = 1;

            }, true);

            $scope.$watch('search.$', function (newVal, oldVal) {           
                $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.announcementListData, newVal);
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
                $scope.currentPage = 1;

            }, true);

            $scope.$watch('search.title', function (newVal, oldVal) {           
                $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.announcementListData, newVal);
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
                $scope.currentPage = 1;

            }, true);


        }]);
```

Comment: Code is a bit long. Can u put it on some jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry . I dont know the procedure to put it in fiddle?

Comment: Basically copy/paste and add all external resources you use - jquery, angular etc. You add external resources on left side. https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the function out of the $watch declaration, and then reference it.

```
$scope.$watch('search.date', updateSearch, true);
$scope.$watch('search.$', updateSearch, true);
$scope.$watch('search.title', updateSearch, true);

function updateSearch(newVal) {           
  $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.announcementListData, newVal);
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
  $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
}
```

Alternatively, if you only wanted a single watch declaration you could do something like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
   return {date: $scope.search.date, $: $scope.search.$, title: $scope.search.title}
  }, function(searchParams){
    // searchParams will now only get run when the object created above changes, 
    // so if any of the fields change, it should pass the updated object in to this function
    $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.announcementListData, searchParams);
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
  }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution .its working with first solution